# lying seven with a marshal up his ass

Tags: meaning

I am really clueless about this one:

> By the time he got his saggy ass to the doctor, he was already **lying
>   seven with a marshal up his ass**.

Can somebody help?

They were talking about golf in this film before. Not sure if related here, though. They are talking about a terminally ill person. But what does that phrase mean?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Educated guess: The longest hole on a golf course is almost always a par 5 hole.  "Lying X" means "You have already taken X shots (on the current hole)" so "Lying 7" is doing very poorly, you are guaranteed at least a triple-bogey, probably worse.  I'm only guessing on the "marshall up his ass", but it's probably a course marshal who monitors play, which means he can't cheat and write a lower score than he actually got on his scorecard.  So basically the guy was doing very poorly and appeared to have no way to improve.

Comment: Wow! Hellion! Absolutely wonderful answer. Really complete explanation. It definitely sounds like it could be golf-related. Thanks so much!

Comment: At some golf courses, a marshal will come push you along if you're stuck too long on a hole (and holding up other golfers). "Lying seven with a marshal up his ass" is just a way of expressing (in golf terms) that "he" is in an especially bad condition.

Comment: Thanks so much! Difficult to guess if you are not familiar with golf.

Comment: @Hellion looks like you've got the best part of a formal answer there. Would you have a go at converting your comment into an answer? You could include R Mac's comment for further reference :-)

Comment: Yeah, I really think that colorful image was a loss to many. I would have literally "blanked" completely on the meaning of the whole second part of the sentence, and just "gathered" from context of the beginning phrase that he sought the doctor much later than he should have.

Answer (score 3):

That is indeed a golf-based metaphor.

Generally speaking, on a golf course the longest hole you will find will be a par-5, meaning you are expected to get your ball from the tee into the cup in 5 strokes.  "[Lying X](https://www.thoughtco.com/lie-in-golf-1560896)" is a golf term meaning "the number of strokes you took to get the ball to where it currently is."  So, if you are lying 7, you have already taken 7 strokes, which is at least 2 more than you wanted to be taking—especially since you're not finished with the hole yet.  So this is a golfing way of saying "doing very badly".

"With a marshal up his ass" refers to a *[course marshal](https://www.thoughtco.com/marshal-golf-definition-1560906)*, whose job (in general terms) is to help keep players moving through the course smoothly.  In particular, they are expected identify slow-playing groups and find ways to help them speed up.  In some cases they may also identify and help control or eject players acting in a disruptive or dangerous fashion (e.g. protracted bouts of loud swearing or arguing, repeatedly endangering others by hitting their ball before the group ahead of them has cleared the target area).  Regardless, having a marshal "up your ass" basically means that the marshal is actively trying to make you do something because they have identified you as the source of a problem, so it's also a bad thing.

You can think of "lying 7" as 'playing the game poorly' and "with a marshal up his ass" as 'managing the process of playing poorly', so it's a golf-ish way of saying that the person is in trouble on multiple levels.